# IN Frappe, I Got A Error "InvalidEmailCredentials" When Creating New User

Tags: python, frappe

When i try to create new user in frappe framewwork then "InvalidEmailCredentials" [Invalid Cred Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxsMx.png) like error occur,
and when i hit request again with same credentials i got a error like "Email id already exist" [error, User with this email already exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z9d1.png). It's mean a email id added but when i login with same credentials, got a login failed.

used @frappe.whitelist method,

Comment: Don't post [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).